# How do I exclude rows in R based on multiple values?

Tags: r, subset

Let's say I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
> data
  iso3 Vaccine Coverage
1  ARG    DPT3       95
2  ARG     MCV       94
3  ARG    Pol3       91
4  KAZ    DPT3       99
5  KAZ     MCV       98
6  KAZ    Pol3       99
7  COD    DPT3       67
8  COD     MCV       62
9  COD    Pol3       66
```

I want to filter out some records based on several conditions being met simultaneously; say, I want to drop any data from Argentina (ARG) with a coverage of more than 93 percent.  The result should thus exclude rows 1 and 2:

```
  iso3 Vaccine Coverage
3  ARG    Pol3       91
4  KAZ    DPT3       99
5  KAZ     MCV       98
6  KAZ    Pol3       99
7  COD    DPT3       67
8  COD     MCV       62
9  COD    Pol3       66
```

I tried using `subset()` but it excludes too much:

```
> subset(data, iso3!="ARG" & Coverage>93)
  iso3 Vaccine Coverage
4  KAZ    DPT3       99
5  KAZ     MCV       98
6  KAZ    Pol3       99
```

The problem seems to be that the `&` operator doesn't seem to work like the boolean AND, returning the intersection of the two conditions.  Instead, it functions like a boolean OR, returning their union.

My question is, what do I use here to force the boolean AND?

Comment: It can be less confusing if you use `with`, e.g. `with(df, !(iso3 == "ARG" & Coverage > 93))`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`!=` is an operator meaning "not equal".

`!` indicates logical negation (`NOT`)

Your condition

```
iso3!="ARG" & Coverage>93
```

is

(iso3 **not equal** to "ARG") AND (Coverage > 93)

If you want

NOT((iso equal to "ARG") AND (Coverage > 93))

You need to create a condition appropriately, eg

eg

```
!(iso == 'ARG' & Coverage > 93)
```

For a complete coverage of logical operators in base R see

```
help('Logic', package='base')
```